# Child view model modying a different child viewmodel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a main View Model for my screen. It consists of 2 child view models.

One handles the registration section.
One handles the login section.
One handles the menu section (If authenticated and what menu items can appear, as well as the "Welcome "Username" type stuff).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Create the main View Model
    var vm = {
        loginVm: new LoginViewModel(),
        registerVm: new RegisterViewModel(),
        layoutVm: new LayoutViewModel()
    }

    // Get the Reference data
    var uri = '/api/Reference/GetTimezones';
    $.getJSON({ url: uri, contentType: "application/json" })
            .done(function (data) {
                vm.registerVm.Timezones(data);
            });

    // Bind.
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

Once my Login model's "Login" method completes, I want to set the "IsAthenticated" value within the Menu model, as well as some other user info.

So in my login model, I have a SignIn method.

```
$.post({ url: uri, contentType: "application/json" }, logindata)
    .done(function (data) {
        toastr[data.StatusText](data.DisplayMessage, data.Heading);
        if (data.StatusText == 'success') {
            alert($parent.layoutVm.IsAuthenticated());
        }
        else {
        }
    })
    .fail(function () {
        toastr['error']("An unexpected error has occured and has been logged. Sorry about tbis! We'll resolve it as soon as possible.", "Error");
    });
```

The alert code is my testing. I am hoping to access (and set) the IsAuthenticated property of the layoutVm model. That's one of the child models on my main View model.

However, "$parent" is not defined.

How can I update values in the layoutVm, from my loginVm?

Comment: I presume that a SignIn call is made after a user action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$parent` is part of the *[binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)*, which is only available *during the evaluation of the data-bind* (i.e. to the binding handler).

In your viewmodel structure, you'll have to come up with a way to communicate between models yourself. For example, by passing parent view models, or by passing along shared observables. The problem you're describing can be solved by using `data-bind="visible: $root.userVM.IsAuthenticated"`, like I answered in your previous question.

If you'd like to go with the other approach, here's an example on how to *share* an observable between viewmodels.

```js
var ChildViewModel = function(sharedObs) {
  this.myObs = sharedObs;
  this.setObs = function() {
    this.myObs(!this.myObs());
  }.bind(this);
}

var RootViewModel = function() {
  this.myObs = ko.observable(false);

  this.vm1 = new ChildViewModel(this.myObs);
  this.vm2 = new ChildViewModel(this.myObs);
  this.vm3 = new ChildViewModel(this.myObs);
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```css
div { width: 25%; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: vm1">
  <h4>vm1</h4>
  <p data-bind="text: myObs"></p>
  <button data-bind="click: setObs">
    flip
  </button>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: vm2">
  <h4>vm2</h4>
  <p data-bind="text: myObs"></p>
  <button data-bind="click: setObs">
    flip
  </button>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: vm3">
  <h4>vm3</h4>
  <p data-bind="text: myObs"></p>
  <button data-bind="click: setObs">
    flip
  </button>
</div>
```

*Note that each of the child view models also have write permission, so you'll have to be careful to not accidentally update the observable*